# Reset button in exposed forms in Drupal

Tags: forms, drupal, reset

I have an exposed form in Drupal and I want to add a simple 'reset' button so all filters will be reset and empty. I found a lot of documentation on D5 or D6, but not on D7.
I thought I'll add a button which links to the current page and by so, resetting all filters, but I'm not sure that's the right thing to do. Any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are talking about views then go to

Exposed form >> settings >>

There is a check box for  reset button. Check that and you should be done.

don't forget to save the view.

Cheers,
vishal

Comment: Yep, I'm talking about views in Drupal 7 (!), where can I find those Exposed form-settings?

Comment: How do you move the reset button? For instance let's say I want it to be before the fields in the form rather than after. How do I move it where it comes before the fields?